# How to add "invisible walls" with SDL2

Tags: sdl, area

Se we are programming a game and in the center of the map there's area where the player cant go.

How we should create that area?

Game is top down perspective.

Comment: Try providing relevant information and be more specific, please.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using some kind of collision detection that stops the player from going certain places (like off screen), all you have to do is to add an object that you can check for collisions with for the area where you don't want to player to go. Given that you haven't provided any specific information on how your game works this is the most specific answer you're likely to get.

Answer (score 0):

Make an `SDL_Rect` that encompasses the entrance to the area, then check the collision of the `SDL_Rect` and the player

Answer (score 0):

You will need some kind of collision detection as already mentioned above.

Then when moving the player, just check if the new position would collide with the rectangle in the middle of the screen.

Something like...

```
if( Input == Walk_Right) 
{ 
   //Move Player
   MovePlayerRight(); 
   //If Player collides with MiddleRect, move back
   if (CheckCollison(&PlayerRect, &BoxRect) == true) MovePlayerLeft();
}
```

Check online for Collusion Detection. Simple Box Method should be enough to check if two Rectangles touch.